# Accumulator pattern with unpacking dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary with a list of countries and gold medals it has won. I added the country Chile on there twice to see if I could incorporate an Accumulator Pattern.  Chile has values of 13 and 122 in the dictionary.

For some reason, when I run my code, the output for chile_golds is 122 instead of 135. Can someone tell me where my code is wrong? I would like to sum up the number of medals when the For Loop encounters "Chile" in the dictionary.

Thank you very much.

```
total_golds = {"Italy": 114, "Germany": 782, "Pakistan": 10, "Sweden": 627, "USA": 2681, "Zimbabwe": 8, "Greece": 111, "Mongolia": 24, "Brazil": 108, "Croatia": 34, "Algeria": 15, "Switzerland": 323, "Yugoslavia": 87, "China": 526, "Egypt": 26, "Norway": 477, "Spain": 133, "Australia": 480, "Slovakia": 29, "Canada": 22, "New Zealand": 100, "Denmark": 180, "Chile": 13, "Argentina": 70, "Thailand": 24, "Cuba": 209, "Uganda": 7,  "England": 806, "Denmark": 180, "Chile": 122, "Bahamas": 12}

chile_golds = 0

for k,v in total_golds.items():
  if k == "Chile":
    chile_golds = chile_golds + v

print(chile_golds)
```

Actual Output: 122
Expected Output: 135

Comment: A `dict` can only have one value for each unique key. You're putting the key `"Chile"` into the dict twice, and so the first value (13) gets overwritten by the second value (122). The `for` loop only encounters one `"Chile"` key, and adds only that value.

Answer (score 2):

In Python, a dictionary is not supposed to have multiple keys ("Chile" in the example). In that situation only one entry is stored in `total_golds` variable. Other data structures should be used instead. Usually a list of tuples can be used:

```
total_golds = [("Italy", 114), ... ]
```

Another possibility is to use a list of dicts. Then using `Counter` from `collections` makes your task trivial because "accumulator pattern" is part of `sum` function:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> total_golds = [{"Italy": 114}, {"Chile": 122}, {"Chile": 13}]
>>> counted = sum([Counter(chunk) for chunk in total_golds], Counter())
>>> print(counted["Chile"])
135
```

Deciding which data structure to use is usually dictated by which operation is prevalent. Dictionary allows fast retrieval of the value by the key. List of items may serve better when one needs to iterate through the sequence one by one.

In the above, list comprehension can be replaced by generator expression:

```
counted = sum((Counter(chunk) for chunk in total_golds), Counter())
```

Comment: I see. That must be why it does not work then. Than you for clarifying this important point!

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to keep the `dict` structure, use `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

d = Counter({'Chile': 3})
d.update(Chile=10)
print(d)
```

Output

```
Counter({'Chile': 13})
```

Unlike the original `dict`, `Counter.update` add counts instead of replacing them.

Comment: I had similar idea of using Counter, but more wired for batch-processing. Thanks for encouraging to add it!